# How can I autopopulate values of a column based on another column in a Shiny rHandsontable?

Tags: r, shiny, vlookup, rhandsontable, rshiny

I'm struggling to get a shiny table (rhandsontable) populated row by row in RShiny via a vlookup-like solution.

I need to replace the NA values in a *manager* column by choosing the region in a *region* column with a drodpdown.

I have the main set (mainData) and the lookup set (lupData), as follows:

**mainData**:

```
# A tibble: 15 x 5
   centre              date     sales region manager
   <chr>               <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
 1 east shopping mall  1/1/2021    50 NA     NA     
 2 west shopping mall  1/1/2021    20 NA     NA     
 3 west shopping mall  1/1/2021    10 NA     NA     
 4 east shopping mall  1/2/2021    15 NA     NA     
 5 east shopping mall  1/2/2021    40 NA     NA     
 6 west shopping mall  1/2/2021    20 NA     NA     
 7 west shopping mall  1/3/2021    15 NA     NA     
 8 east shopping mall  1/4/2021     5 NA     NA     
 9 east shopping mall  1/4/2021    60 NA     NA     
10 south shopping mall 1/5/2021    66 NA     NA     
11 south shopping mall 1/6/2021    44 NA     NA     
12 south shopping mall 1/7/2021     3 NA     NA     
13 west shopping mall  1/5/2021    75 NA     NA     
14 west shopping mall  1/6/2021    14 NA     NA     
15 east shopping mall  1/7/2021     8 NA     NA
```

**lupData**:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  region manager
  <chr>  <chr>  
1 East   Mxolisi
2 West   Tom    
3 South  Philani
```

I want to add a dropdown on the *region* column, after reading which shopping centre the sales come from (i.e. the first column *centre*).
Then I want the *manager* column populated automatically after choosing (with the dropdown) the *region* I think/decided that specific shopping center is from.

Please refer to my snippet code, where the output I get on my dropdown don't seem to exhibit the required link to the *manager* feature:

```r
    library(shiny)
    library(rhandsontable)
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      p(),
      rHandsontableOutput("hot", width = "100%", height = "100%")
    )
    
    server = function(input, output, session){
      
      DF <- data.frame("centre" = as.factor(c("east shopping mall",  "west shopping mall",  "west shopping mall",  "east shopping mall",  "east shopping mall", 
                                             "west shopping mall",  "west shopping mall",  "east shopping mall",  "east shopping mall",  "south shopping mall",
                                             "south shopping mall", "south shopping mall", "west shopping mall",  "west shopping mall",  "east shopping mall")),
                       "date" = as.Date(c("1/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/2/2021", "1/3/2021", "1/4/2021", "1/4/2021", "1/3/2021",
                                          "1/9/2021", "1/11/2021", "1/5/2021", "1/6/2021", "1/7/2021")),
                       "sales" = as.integer(c(50, 20, 10, 15, 40, 20, 15,  5, 60, 66, 44,  3, 75, 14,  8)),
    
    #my dropdown column region (must also populate manager) 
                       "region"= rep(as.factor(c("East",  "West",  "South")), length = length(c(50, 20, 10, 15, 40, 20, 15,  5, 60, 66, 44,  3, 75, 14,  8)))#i.e. max rows on the main table
                       
    ,"manager"= rep(as.factor(c("Mxolisi",  "Tom",  "Jerry")), length = length(c(50, 20, 10, 15, 40, 20, 15,  5, 60, 66, 44,  3, 75, 14,  8)))
                       )
      
    values <- reactiveValues(data = DF)
      
      observe({
        if(!is.null(input$hot)){
          values$data <- as.data.frame(hot_to_r(input$hot))
        }
      })    
      
      output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
        
        myTable <- rhandsontable(values$data, width = 1750, height = 5500, selectCallback = TRUE) %>%
          hot_table(highlightCol = TRUE, highlightRow = TRUE, stretchH = "all") %>% 
          hot_col(col = "region", type = "dropdown", source = NULL, readOnly = TRUE, allowInvalid = FALSE)
        
        if(!is.null(input$hot_select$select$r) ){
          myTable <- hot_col(myTable, col = "region", type = "dropdown", source = values$DF$region[input$hot_select$select$r], readOnly = T)%>% 
            hot_cell(input$hot_select$select$r, col = "region", readOnly = FALSE)
        }
        
    myTable
        
      })
      
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your "manager" column conditionnally based on the "region" column, you can do it by observing and updating the `reactiveValues` dataframe with the following code (inserted below the creation of the `values` object):

```
  observe({
    df <- values$data
    df$manager <- ifelse(df$region == "East", "Mxolisi",
                         ifelse(df$region == "West", "Tom", "Jerry"))
    values$data <- df
  })
```